# Show that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac {z^n} {n}$ converges when $|z| = 1$ , except when $z =1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm stuck at this one. If $z \ne 1$, can I show this by invoking that when $|z| = 1$ then $z = e^ {i \theta}$ where $\theta = arg (z)$?

Comment: Hint: It does not converge at $z=1$.

Comment: It surely doesn't converge for $z=1$.

Comment: I'm not convinced on this... Let $z=1$ and then we have the Harmonic series

Comment: It's convergent when $|z|=1$ with $z\neq 1$.

Comment: Made the changes. When $z = 1$ it's a harmonic series that's known to diverge.